# Why would Windows PowerShell slow startup?

Tags: windows-vista, powershell

After installing the program my start up time increased by about 30 seconds. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing a few restarts - sometimes the first restart after any software install can be a little slower.

Other things to try:

1) Defrag your hard drive.

2) Use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to see if anything else you have installed recently is starting with the machine.

(If you just mean PowerShell is slow to start - it is a .Net program, the first time you run it, it needs to be recompiled... subsequent runs are usually a lot faster/instant.)

Comment: You were right. After TWO restarts, things were back to normal. Who'd a' thunk it? ... Thanks for your help.